# Probability that a random variable is less than 4. (help in R)

Tags: statistics

Let $Y_1,Y_2,\ldots,Y_n$ be independent and identically distributed normal random variables with mean 5, and variance 16. Let $n=10$, use R to find $prob(\overline{Y} \leq 4)$ where $\overline{Y}$ is the mean of $Y_1,Y_2,\ldots,Y_n$.

I know how to set up the distribution oh $\overline{Y}$ in R, but I'm completely blanking on how to extract that probability from knowing the distribution.

To set up the distribution in R, we write:

> Y <- rnorm(100000, 5, 4)
>   Y <- matrix(Y, byrow = T, ncol = 10)
>   Y_Means <- apply(Y, 1, mean)

Now that we have the distribution (Y_Means), how to find probability?

Comment: The random variable $\bar{Y}$ has normal distribution, mean $5$, variance $\frac{16}{10}$.

Comment: mean(Y_Means < 4) ought to do it. But you can compute the desired probability exactly, using the comment by André.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\var}{\operatorname{var}}$ $\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb E}$

You're making this immensely more complicated than it is.

You've got
$$
\E\left(\frac{Y_1+\cdots+Y_n}{n}\right) = 5
$$
and
$$
\var\left(\frac{Y_1+\cdots+Y_n}{n}\right) = \frac{16}{n}.
$$
Therefore
$$
\frac{(Y_1+\cdots+Y_n)/n-5}{\sqrt{16/n\,{}}} \sim N(0,1).
$$
So
$$
\Pr\left(\frac{Y_1+\cdots+Y_n}{n}\le 4\right) = \Pr\left(\frac{(Y_1+\cdots+Y_n)/n-5}{\sqrt{16/n\,{}}} \le \frac{4-5}{\sqrt{16n\,{}}}\right) = \Pr\left(Z\le\frac{4-5}{\sqrt{16n\,{}}}\right)
$$
where $Z\sim N(0,1)$.

So plug $\dfrac{4-5}{\sqrt{16n\,{}}}$ into the cumulative distribution function of the standard normal distribution.  That cumulative distribution function is computed by a standard R command, pnorm if I recall correctly.